# Obter dia de semana através de uma date LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Necessito de obter um conjunto de registo de um respectivo dia de semana(Exemplo Segunda), onde para isso tenho um campo na tabela do tipo datetime.

Em Sql ficaria algo do género:

```
SELECT AVG(P.Quant) AS Expr1
FROM     P
WHERE  (Pro.Tipo = 'B') AND (V.ID= 1)
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM P.data) = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `SqlFunctions.DatePart`, que permite obter as partes de uma data dentro de uma query LINQ-To-Entities:

Creio que ficaria como algo desse tipo:

```
var resultado = db.P
    .Where(x => x.Tipo == "B" && x.Id == 1)
    .Where(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x => x.data) == 2);
```

Ou se for LINQ-To-SQL, pode usar a propriedade `DayOfWeek` da data:

```
var resultado = db.P
    .Where(x => x.Tipo == "B" && x.Id == 1)
    .Where(x => x => x.data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
```